# django-rest-auth create userprofile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-registration, django-rest-auth

I'm using [django-rest-auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to handle login and registration. The problem that I stumbled upon is that I'd like to add some custom fields to the default `django User model`. I've seen they covering this on their docs and I've tried replicating their example from [here](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html), but when I am making a PUT request for the newly created field from the userprofile I get this error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /rest-auth/user/
User has no userprofile.
Request Method: PUT
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/user/
Django Version: 2.2.10
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no userprofile.
Exception Location: /home/terkea/django_react_template/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __get__, line 415
Python Executable:  /home/terkea/django_react_template/src/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.9
Python Path:    
['/home/terkea/django_react_template/src',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/terkea/django_react_template/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 10 Apr 2020 14:56:41 +0000
```

This is my model

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

and here's my serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.serializers import UserDetailsSerializer


class UserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):

    company_name = serializers.CharField(source="userprofile.company_name")

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + ('company_name',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})
        company_name = profile_data.get('company_name')

        instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        # get and update user profile
        profile = instance.userprofile
        if profile_data and company_name:
            profile.company_name = company_name
            profile.save()
        return instance
```

I am assuming that the userprofile entry has to be created at the same time when the user is, but I don't know how exactly should I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_for_user(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

this solved my problem